# Can you calculate kinetic energy with the rocket equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rocket-science

Is it possible to calculate kinetic energy with the rocket equation? I am doing a quick school project on the efficiency of a rocket.

What if we write velocity with the kinetic energy formula.

$E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

$v=\sqrt{\frac{2E_k}{m}}$

the rocket equation: $\Delta v = I_{sp}g_0\ln(\frac{m_0}{m_f})$

$$
E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\Rightarrow v=\Delta v=\sqrt{\frac{2E_k}{m}}=I_{sp}g_0\ln{\left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)}
$$
$$\frac{2E_k}{m}=\left(I_{sp}g_0\ln{\left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)}\right)^2 \Rightarrow E_k=\frac{1}{2}m\left(I_{sp}g_0\ln{\left(\frac{m_0}{m_f}\right)}\right)^2$$

I would say something is not right because how can you know kinetic energy without knowing the velocity of the object. Something just does not click. I hope I did not make any math errors. I would like to thank you for reading.

Comment: I think your worries are empty. Tsiolkovsky rocket equation gives a maximum rocket speed after it completely burns-out $m_0 - m_f$ amount of propellant. So final speed is intrinsic property of "how much fuel it takes" to achieve $v = v_0 + \Delta v$.

Comment: would you explain all the symbols please, especially $I_{sp}$ and $g_0$?

Comment: $I_{sp}$ - is specific impulse, Characteristic of rocket engine and fuel, More about that here - https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/specimp.html   $g_0 = 9.8 m/s^2$